# Controller Doesn't accept my request. It always show 404 not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, servlets

I am creating a spring Maven application which to send email.I just started the project and getting error 404 not found. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried changing the dependencies of dispatcher servlet and checked if request goes to specific method but it seems, request never accepted by the controller.

Here is configuration:

index.jsp

```
<a href="compose">Compose</a>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet> 
    <servlet-name>frontController</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class> 
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>frontController</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

frontController-servlet.xml

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvc.mainController.ControllerDemo"> 
     </context:component-scan> 
 <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven> 
 <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
     <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property> 
     <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property> 
 <bean>
```

ControllerDemo.java

```
@RequestMapping("/compose")
public String compose()
{
    System.out.println("Request Received...");
    return "new";
}
```

It never accepts request.

Comment: Did you add a `@Controller` Annotation to the ControllerDemo Class?

Comment: Have you tried any other posts in so? Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7785394/1160106

Comment: base-package expects a base **package**. You're giving it a controller class name.

Comment: If this is a new application, don't use these obsolete techniques. Use Spring Boot instead, which makes this whole configuration automatic. (And I strongly recommend Thymeleaf instead of JSP, especially if you're going to send e-mail, since it works well as an e-mail template engine but JSP doesn't.)

Comment: Thanks to all for your help!

 Yes, I used @Controller Annotation in ControllerDemo class. 

You're correct Johnathan that's the reason I used ControllerDemo which shouldn't create any ambiguity in origin Controller class and my Controller.

Comment: Issue resolved.@JBNizet is correct I just checked the project configuration and found i was giving Controller class instead of base package.

Thanks @chrylis for suggestion, I'll surely see what things are in Thymeleaf :)